# How can I iterate a state array in a .map() method of a "context"?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-context, react-component

It is a bit hard to explain my problem, but I hope someone can help, I have a context that I get objects from and I using .map() to use cards and show the data, like this:

```
const { user_data, classes } = this.context;
        return(
          <div className="App">
              
              <h1>Hello, {user_data.first_name}</h1>
              <Container className= "MainContainer" style={{marginTop: "30px", marginLeft: "10%", width: "80%"}}>
                  <Row>
                    {classes.map(Class => {
                        <Link 
                            to={{
                                pathname : `/Class/${Class.Name}`,
                                state: {
                                Name: Class.Name, 
                                ClassNumber: Class.CLassNumber,
                                identification: Class.Identification
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <Col className="col-md-4" >
                                <Card style={{ width: '18rem', zIndex: '0', marginTop:"20px" }}>
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>{Class.Name}</Card.Title>
                                        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted"> 

                                        </Card.Subtitle>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            </Col>
                        </Link>
                    })}
                  </Row>
              </Container>
          </div>
```

And I also used .map() with the classes I got from the context to use a get() method from axios and get the data from an api , honestly I don't know if I did it right, but I did it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
      const { classes } = this.context;
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        {classes.map(Class => (
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Users/teacher/${Class.Teacher}`, config)
                .then(
                    res => {
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            TeacherName: [
                                ...prevState.TeacherName,
                                res.data
                            ]
                        })
                        );
                    }
                )
        ))}                         
      }
```

Now if what I did is correct, What I want to do is connect each class with the corresponding Teacher, and I cannot do it in the backend "django", because I am using a foreign key for the Teacher and it sends the id of the teacher not the name, so how can I connect the teacher that I supposedly get from the api in react to the class that I get from the context??

Please help me, I would very much appreciate it

Comment: Assuming `classes` is an `array` of `obj`,  you are fetching data over `.map()`. I don't think that a good practice. Do you able to get any data from tht?

Comment: you are right, it does not work, do you suggest another way to solve the problem??

Comment: do you get any data at all? From the `.map()`? Anyway, I didn't able to get it work with `axios .map()`. But, **matching** & **combining** method proven successful. you can see this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5urnmg) I just made.